# Applying a function only works for one column instead of multiple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apply, data-manipulation

```
x = [{'list1':'[1,6]', 'list2':'[1,1]'},
     {'list1':'[1,7]', 'list2':'[1,2]'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Now I'm going to transform it from string to list type:

```
df[['list1','list2']].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x.strip()))

>> ("'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'", 'occurred at index list1')
```

So I get an error, but if I single out only 1 column:

```
d['list1'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x.strip()))

>>    0    [1, 6]
      1    [1, 7]
      Name: list1, dtype: object
```

Why is this happening? Why does it only allow one column instead of multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand how [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is supposed to work in order to understand why it isn't working for you. Each column (considering the default `axis=0`) is iteratively operated upon, you can see how by letting each series print itself:

```
df.apply(lambda x: print(x))
0    [1,6]
1    [1,7]
Name: list1, dtype: object
0    [1,1]
1    [1,2]
Name: list2, dtype: object
```

And when you try and call `(series_object).strip()`, the error makes more sense.

---

Since you want to apply your function to each cell individually, you can use `applymap` instead, it's relatively faster in comparison.

```
df[['list1','list2']].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Or,

```
df[['list1','list2']].applymap(pd.eval)
```

```
    list1   list2
0  [1, 6]  [1, 1]
1  [1, 7]  [1, 2]
```

Other options also include:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.map(ast.literal_eval))

    list1   list2
0  [1, 6]  [1, 1]
1  [1, 7]  [1, 2]
```

Among others.